# Jquery selector + получить value

Tags: jquery

Как заселектить этот элемент через jquery + взять его value?

```
<input type="text" spellcheck="false" data-some="getthis" height="55px" class="someclass" value="valuehere">
```

Нужно заселектить по `data-some` и его value (`getthis`) а получить `valuehere`.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
    let val = $('[data-some="getthis"]').val();
    console.log(val);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" spellcheck="false" data-some="getthis" height="55px" class="someclass" value="valuehere">
```

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но я так и делал.
Отдаёт undefined, видимо проблема в чем-то другом. :(